# Postgresql streaming replication, server closed the connection

Tags: postgresql, replication, write-ahead-logging

I set up delayed replication (DB3), which receives WALs from another replication (DB2), it was working fine for few days then this happened:

```
DB3
2023-04-29 05:51:34.483 CEST,,,7292,,6447d887.1c7c,2,,2023-04-25 15:41:27 CEST,,0,FATAL,XX000,"could not receive data from WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.",,,,,,,,,"","walreceiver"


DB2
2023-04-29 05:51:24.578 CEST,"rep_user","",9424,"10.52.13.18:15761",6447d887.24d0,1,"",2023-04-25 15:41:27 CEST,36/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    
",,,,,,"START_REPLICATION 74CC/B5000000 TIMELINE 1",,,"walreceiver","walsender"
```

After that, DB3 stopped to download new WAL files.

I had `wal_receiver_timeout = 60s` and `recovery_min_apply_delay = 1d` on DB3
and `wal_sender_timeout = 60s` on DB2.

What is strange that there's data 2023-**04-25** 15:41:27 in the error log, 4 days before connection closed.

Why is that, and why postgres didn't try to re-establish WAL streaming?

Comment: Why are there two timestamps per entry in your log file in the first place?  How is your logging configured?